# how to pass parameter in angular catch block

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Wanted to see if this was possible and if so how. On Angular's `.catch` block, I want to have my handleError callback and pass an id. but regardless the function gets called, I know it because of how the promise is formed. but I was hoping there was a way to still pass in a parameter without calling the function beforehand.

```js
//controller
function handleError(id) {
  showErrorMessage(id);
}

callFactory
  .then(update)
  .catch(handleError)
  .finally(clearLoader);

// would like to use something like this.

callFactory
  .then(update)
  .catch(handleError(2)) //this gets called regardless
  .finally(clearLoader);
```

Comment: Use a function factory that returns a custom version of `handleError` that `catch` can call.

Comment: yeah, that's what I currently have. just curious if the above was possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first argument of the `.catch` is always going to be the exception that was thrown. You could probably achieve what you're looking for with a  closure method. Something like:

```
function handleError(id) {
  return function(err) {
    // access to both err and id
}
```

Altertnatively, you could `throw` the id in the `.catch`, then it would be picked up by the next `catch`

```
.catch(err=> { throw id })
.catch(id=> ... )
```

Comment: Closure FTW! Thanks, Austin.